# Why does this query return the first row instead of the name and country that has the most yellowcard

Tags: sql

I have a database of soccer teams.

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT
    players.Name,
    players.Country
FROM
    players
WHERE
    players.Player_id = (SELECT player_cards.Player_id
                         FROM player_cards
                         HAVING MAX(player_cards.Yellow_Cards));
```

But it only returns the name and country of the player in the first row instead of the info of the player with the most yellow cards.

Why is this happening? How should I fix it?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

The subquery that you *want* is:

```
players.Player_id = (SELECT pc.Player_id
                     FROM player_cards pc
                     ORDER BY pc.Yellow_Cards DESC
                     LIMIT 1
                    );
```

Note that if you have duplicates, this returns only one max value.

Why doesn't yours work?  First, it is not really valid SQL, because the `HAVING` clause makes this an aggregation query . . . and without a `GROUP BY` there should be no unaggregated columns in the `SELECT`.  You have one, so I am guessing that you are using an older version of MySQL.

What does the query do?  It returns one row because of the `MAX()` in the `HAVING` clause.  The one row has an *arbitrary* value of `Player_id` -- which might be the "first" row or any row.  Which row the value comes from is undefined.

The `HAVING` clause serves two purposes.  It makes the query an aggregation query that returns exactly one row.  And it validates that the maximum value of the column is not `0` or `NULL`.

Comment: Adding to this answer, there is also the situation where you have multiple players that have received the same number of 'max' yellow cards that you'll have to account for in this query, so you shouldn't really be expecting 1 record every time in return imo